# Is there a way to correct bad JSON that won't decode in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have some JSON data i retrieved from a shell_exec service (pulling data from soundcloud) - however when there are multiple entries PHP throws a error 4 (json_last_error) for when json_decode is attempted on the JSON

Here is an example of the JSON:

```
{
    "display_id": "142993814",
    "upload_date": "20140404",
    "protocol": "http",
    "description": "~~~",
    "extractor": "soundcloud:set",
    "_filename": "/home/test/public/test.com/public/music_uploads/LYKOS - R E B I R T H.mp3",
    "uploader": "LYKOS",
    "duration": 240,
    "format_id": "http_mp3_128_url",
    "id": "142993814",
    "playlist_title": "LYKOS - R E B I R T H",
    "stitle": "R E B I R T H",
    "playlist": "LYKOS - R E B I R T H",
    "title": "R E B I R T H",
    "url": "https://ec-media.soundcloud.com/6phvZ45fCues.128.mp3?f10880d39085a94a0418a7ef69b03d522cd6dfee9399eeb9a522009566ffb6384d14cc1e49211bff90254e635b6f302484775d5b068cf60f94aba5cbe81c4fae5b4e5a43e2&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJNIGGLK7XA7YZSNQ&Expires=1419978413&Signature=hImHseUqea1dvmdpFBTv41s17WE%3D",
    "extractor_key": "SoundcloudSet",
    "vcodec": "none",
    "format": "http_mp3_128_url - audio only",
    "playlist_index": 1,
    "playlist_id": 63174483,
    "ext": "mp3",
    "webpage_url_basename": "lykos-r-e-b-i-r-t-h",
    "webpage_url": "http://soundcloud.com/lykosss/r-e-b-i-r-t-h",
    "formats": [
        {
            "url": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/142993814/stream?client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28",
            "format_id": "fallback",
            "ext": "mp3",
            "vcodec": "none",
            "format": "fallback - audio only"
        },
        {
            "protocol": "http",
            "format": "http_mp3_128_url - audio only",
            "url": "https://ec-media.soundcloud.com/6phvZ45fCues.128.mp3?f10880d39085a94a0418a7ef69b03d522cd6dfee9399eeb9a522009566ffb6384d14cc1e49211bff90254e635b6f302484775d5b068cf60f94aba5cbe81c4fae5b4e5a43e2&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJNIGGLK7XA7YZSNQ&Expires=1419978413&Signature=hImHseUqea1dvmdpFBTv41s17WE%3D",
            "vcodec": "none",
            "ext": "mp3",
            "format_id": "http_mp3_128_url"
        }
    ],
    "fulltitle": "R E B I R T H",
    "thumbnail": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000099699341-ygkqvo-t500x500.jpg",
    "n_entries": 13
}{
    "display_id": "143857955",
    "upload_date": "20140409",
    "protocol": "http",
    "description": "~~~dreaming~~~",
    "extractor": "soundcloud:set",
    "_filename": "/home/test/public/test.com/public/music_uploads/LYKOS - S L E E P.mp3",
    "uploader": "LYKOS",
    "duration": 253,
    "format_id": "http_mp3_128_url",
    "id": "143857955",
    "playlist_title": "LYKOS - R E B I R T H",
    "stitle": "S L E E P",
    "playlist": "LYKOS - R E B I R T H",
    "title": "S L E E P",
    "url": "https://ec-media.soundcloud.com/8c5j72R7fUOY.128.mp3?f10880d39085a94a0418a7ef69b03d522cd6dfee9399eeb9a522009566ffb6384e10cc1e49211bff6d1fc6651c7f87f729f813831232cadee16ac0c95d88ce12e0292881ae&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJNIGGLK7XA7YZSNQ&Expires=1419978427&Signature=x60HoNiniDI1swnVXk%2F7fwXc6xo%3D",
    "extractor_key": "SoundcloudSet",
    "vcodec": "none",
    "format": "http_mp3_128_url - audio only",
    "playlist_index": 2,
    "playlist_id": 63174483,
    "ext": "mp3",
    "webpage_url_basename": "lykos-r-e-b-i-r-t-h",
    "webpage_url": "http://soundcloud.com/lykosss/s-l-e-e-p",
    "formats": [
        {
            "url": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/143857955/stream?client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28",
            "format_id": "fallback",
            "ext": "mp3",
            "vcodec": "none",
            "format": "fallback - audio only"
        },
        {
            "protocol": "http",
            "format": "http_mp3_128_url - audio only",
            "url": "https://ec-media.soundcloud.com/8c5j72R7fUOY.128.mp3?f10880d39085a94a0418a7ef69b03d522cd6dfee9399eeb9a522009566ffb6384e10cc1e49211bff6d1fc6651c7f87f729f813831232cadee16ac0c95d88ce12e0292881ae&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJNIGGLK7XA7YZSNQ&Expires=1419978427&Signature=x60HoNiniDI1swnVXk%2F7fwXc6xo%3D",
            "vcodec": "none",
            "ext": "mp3",
            "format_id": "http_mp3_128_url"
        }
    ],
    "fulltitle": "S L E E P",
    "thumbnail": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000076040794-rjgkv4-t500x500.jpg",
    "n_entries": 13
}
```

Is there a way to fix the JSON in php so that is decodable?

Comment: What is a `shell_exec service`?  How are you getting this data?  I doubt SoundCloud is giving you bad JSON.

Comment: @RocketHazmat im doing a shell exec with youtube-dl -j on a url at soundcloud and i save the output of the shell_exec into a variable $output that won't decode with json_decode

Comment: Now that @Axel has edited the JSON to be *readable*, I can see the error.  You have two objects here (notice the `}{` without a comma).  These should be in array, or parsed separately.

Comment: @RocketHazmat http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/ a tool to download videos and audio from different websites!

Comment: You might need to try using `-J` instead of `-j`.  Are you trying to call `youtube-dl` with multiple URLs?

Comment: You should write to SoundCloud to fix that shit. There's no **safe** way to decode it.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan: Sadly, this JSON isn't coming *directly* from SoundCloud.  It's coming from [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/), a third-party script.

Comment: Using a 3rd party tool which obviously is erroneous whilst there's a native API and proven [libs](https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud) is a considerable architecture.

Comment: Can you raise a bug report against the script that is producing invalid JSON, @FightFireWithFire? It may be worth looking through their existing issue list, in case it has already been raised.

Comment: i will - it does produce results that work with -J (and not -j as I was using) as per @RocketHazmat mentioned, but in general it does look like the JSON isn't formed the way most code is looking for.

Comment: @FightFireWithFire: What it's doing is outputting *multiple* JSON strings, instead of just one.  Are you querying 2 URLS or just one?  Maybe when ran on the command-line, there are newlines between the JSON strings?

Answer (score 4):

you may either split that in to to strings which then may parse properly:

```
$twoJsons = explode('}{', $myInputString);

$obj1 = json_decode($twoJsons[0] . '}'); 
...
```

or just replace the wrong `}{` by `},{`:

```
$myJson = '[' . str_replace('}{', '},{', $myInputString) . ']';
```

Comment: The 2nd example should be `$myJson = '['.str_replace('}{', '},{', $myInputString).']';`

Comment: I'm upvoting the second solution ;-)